# long build time for simple function

Tags: ios, optimization, swift3, alamofire

I'm wondering why my function is taking so much time to build. Longest time for me is 206.1ms, this is over 3 minutes !

```
187721.1ms InspectionViewController.swift:423:17    @IBAction @objc func btnSaveTouch(_ sender: Any)
```

I was looking for some optimizations, but can't find any reasonable reason why my function is so slow.

I'm using Alamofire here, and couple of fields (text fields, text views, and 2 x switches)

code looks like that:

```
@IBAction func btnSaveTouch(_ sender: Any) {

        var two_storeys = ""
        var legal_height_downstairs = ""

        if s_two_storeys.isOn {
            two_storeys = "Yes"
        } else {
            two_storeys = "No"
        }

        if s_legal_height_downstairs.isOn {
            legal_height_downstairs = "Yes"
        } else {
            legal_height_downstairs = "No"
        }

        let parameters : Parameters = [
            "inspection_date" : tf_inspection_date.text!,
            "property_type" : tf_property_type.text!,
            "beds" : tf_beds.text!,
            "baths" : tf_baths.text!,
            "cars" : tf_cars.text!,
            "our_price_min" : tf_our_price_min.text!,
            "our_price_max" : tf_our_price_max.text!,
            "max_rent" : tf_rent_max.text!,
            "min_rent" : tf_rent_min.text!,
            "upfront_max": tf_upfront_max.text!,
            "character": tf_character.text!,
            "character_years": tf_character_years.text!,
            "character_uers": tf_character_year.text!,
            "build_construction": tf_build_construction.text!,
            "roof_material":  tv_roof_material.text!,
            "house_on": tf_house_on.text!,
            "two_storeys": two_storeys,
            "legal_height_downstairs": legal_height_downstairs,
            "legal_height_downstairs_value" : tv_legal_height_downstairs_value.text!

        ]

        Alamofire.request(saveUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

            _ = handleError(response: response)


        }

    }
```

Comment: Was the longest build time really 206 ms ? Because that is less than a second. Or did you mean to say seconds?

Comment: Did you try making the same request using an external tool like postman? just to be sure is not your fault, maybe it is just because the endpoints is slow

Comment: The Swift compiler doesn't like big literal dictionaries. Try creating the empty dictionary first and add the values to it. Like `parameters["inspection_date"] = tf_inspection_date.text!` then the next value, etc. I know it's not fun but it's a valid workaround usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so Eric Aya was right. Now compile time for this function is 19.9ms. Working code below.

```
    var paramaters : Parameters = [:]

    paramaters["inspection_date"] = tf_inspection_date.text!
    paramaters["property_type"] = tf_property_type.text!
    paramaters["beds"] = tf_beds.text!
    paramaters["baths"] = tf_baths.text!
    paramaters["cars"] = tf_cars.text!
    paramaters["our_price_min"] = tf_our_price_min.text!
    paramaters["our_price_max"] = tf_our_price_max.text!
    paramaters["max_rent"] = tf_rent_max.text!
    paramaters["min_rent"] = tf_rent_min.text!
    paramaters["upfront_max"] = tf_upfront_max.text!
    paramaters["character"] = tf_character.text!
    paramaters["character_years"] = tf_character_years.text!
    paramaters["character_uers"] = tf_character_year.text!
    paramaters["build_construction"] = tf_build_construction.text!
    paramaters["roof_material"] = tv_roof_material.text!
    paramaters["house_on"] = tf_house_on.text!
    paramaters["two_storeys"] = two_storeys
    paramaters["legal_height_downstairs"] = legal_height_downstairs
    paramaters["legal_height_downstairs_value"] = tv_legal_height_downstairs_value.text!
```

Answering Jeremy's question - Yes, got pretty simple code:

[image]